# Where are the elements of a collection stored in java?

Tags: java, list, collections

I'm new to java and trying to understand where implementations of the Collection interface are storing the elements I add to it. I understand how to work with collections using the various methods, but what I don't understand is what is happening under the hood when I write for example:

```
Collection<Integer> intList= new ArrayList();
intList.add(3);
```

Is a new field created in the class for the element 3? If so how are these various fields linked to one another when I create the iterator?

```
Iterator<Integer> intIter = intList.iterator();
boolean test = intIter.hasNext();
```

Or how are the various elements attached to indices when working with a less general interface like a List?

Comment: Do you know what an [*array*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) is?

Comment: [`ArrayList<E>`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java).

Comment: You need to get familiar with the notion of [*Data structure*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure), then learn about [*Array*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure) and [*Dynamic array*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array). At that point, you will understand that `ArrayList` is an implementation of the Dynamic array data structure offered by the JDK. Your current question *"Where are the elements of a collection stored"* is too broad.

Answer (score 1):

- First of all, `Collection` is just an interface, the implementation is `ArrayList`. So we just focus on the detail of `ArrayList`
- `ArrayList` is implemented with an array internal. So `add(3)` means set the `arr[index] = 3;` The index is from zero.
- View the source code, you will see the `iterator();` is a wrapper for the array visitor. Some key variables is `cursor`, `lastRet`, `expectedModCount`.
- Finally as a new beginner, view source code maybe resolve all your problems.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Collection<Integer> intList= new ArrayList();
> ```

This is syntax sugar. So lets desugar it, to understand what happens. Specifically, this code does 3 mostly unrelated things:

1. Declare a new typed variable, named `intList`.
2. Create a new ArrayList object. Objects do not have names.
3. Copy over the *reference* to this object into the `intList` variable.

In java, all variables (so also all parameters, and all fields) are either "primitive" or "reference". That's exhaustive: Those are the only 2 options. Primitives are all variables whose type is one of the primitive types. The primitive types are hardcoded into the java lang spec. They are `int`, `long`, `double`, `float`, `short`, `byte`, `char`, and `boolean` - and that's it. Those are the 8. Note that `String` is not amongst them.

For the primitives, a variable just stores the value. This is simple: *all* the primitives have the property that their size is fixed and small. At most they are 64 bits, and all CPUs built in the last decade pretty much operate on 64-bit units so that lines up nicely.

For the refs, not so much. A string, for example, can be incredibly large. So, instead, the variable **does not contain the data**. It instead contains **a reference to the data** - a pointer. Except we don't like to call it that because the term 'pointer' has baggage, but make no mistake: It's a pointer.

Here, `intList` is the variable that can only hold *references* (because its type is *not* primitive). `new ArrayList()` creates an entire object and the expression resolves to *a reference*, which is then assigned to the `intList` variable.

Think of it like a gigantic beach. `new ArrayList()` creates a new treasure chest out of thin air, and buries it in the sand. `intList` is not the treasure chest. No, it's a **map** to the treasure chest. The `.` operator is java-ese for: Follow the map and dig up the chest. `intList.add(5)` means: Take your treasure map called `intList`, and walk to the X. Now dig. Now open the treasure chest. Now yell `add(5)` at it. Which does.. whatever the docs say it does. Could be anything, that's the joy of programming.

If you then say `intList = null`, you're not destroying the treasure chest. Nope, you merely erase out your treasure map. The treasure chest is still buried in the sand. However, java has automatic garbage collection: Any treasure with the property that no maps exist anymore that could let you find it, are 'garbage' and will eventually be dug up and tossed out by the garbage collector. In C and some other languages, you can go on arbitrary digging sprees. Not so in java - you **cannot dig**, the language will not let you, unless you have a treasure map to lead the way.

That beach is 'the heap' and it is huge - by default gigabytes or so large, it grows as needed and the garbage collector tosses out the garbage whenever it is neccessary to make some room.

So how does ArrayList work, what is in that treasure chest? Simple: Every non-static field as defined in the `class ArrayList` along with every field in the class mentioned in the extends clause (ArrayList is defined as `class ArrayList extends AbstractList`, so every field AbstractList has too, and so on). Of course, fields are primitive or treasure maps too, so really those treasure chests aren't as large as you might imagine. They really just store numbers and maps, that's all.

So how *does* arraylist work internally? With arrays, hence the name. ArrayList makes an array of 10 and tracks how many slots are actually 'used' (initially, arraylists are empty, so 0 slots used). As you call `.add`, it just fills the array at the current 'used' slot and then increments 'used' by 1. Of course, once you try to add an 11th element that can't be done, so what arraylist's code does is make a new array (poof! a new treasure chest springs into existence, with 20 blank treasure maps inside, as well as a note with room to write down a single number), copies over the 10 existing maps, and then updates its one map that points at 'the treasure chest with all the maps in it' (it's a lot of maps that lead to treasure chests with maps that lead to more chests, and so on!). This means the old treasure chest (the old array) is still around, but garbage. (No map exists that could get you there). Eventually it'll get collected.

If you try to add the 21st element, again this copy thing happens. ArrayList's implementation multiplies by 1.5, I think, every time it needs to grow (so, from 10, to 15, to 23, to 35, etcetera).